# Where the value of object stored in java

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java.
I have studied that reference variable contains the address of the object and the object is stored in Heap memory. Then where the values of object variables are stored.

Comment: The jvm will deal with all that and you don't need to worry about that yourself too much. But anything long lived will be in the heap. Short lived things are stored in assorted ways (partially dependant on the jvm)

Comment: @RichardTingle There are only two options: heap or stack, but the decision does not depend on object longevity (it is theoretically impossible: how could you predict the lifespan of an object upon its creation?).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Google "escape analysis".  :P  While you can't predict how long an object will live once it's left the function, it's not all that difficult to detect that the object does or doesn't leave the function.

Comment: @cHao You know very well that I'm acquainted with the concept. You answer for me this question: what does it matter how long a method takes to execute? What if an object is deemed non-escaped in the method which contains the main program loop?

Comment: @Marko, escape analysis and the stack was indeed what I was refering to. I was deliberately vague because im not in a position to properly research an answer at present

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Then escape analysis shows that the object's lifespan does not exceed the function's.  That's all that matters.  Object life spans are rarely measured in terms of real time; usually it's in terms of scopes and references.

Comment: @cHao My point exactly: it's not about lifespan in seconds and that's why I corrected Richard's initial comment.

Answer (score 1):

> where the values of object variable are stored

If by this you mean "where are the instance variables of the object are stored", then the answer is that they are stored within the memory structure which represents the object. As you say yourself, this would normally be on the heap.

The instance variables may themselves be of reference type, pointing to further objects, which are again stored on the heap (mostly). So normally in Java, you get an *object graph* of interconnected memory structures sprinkled all over the heap. Only values of primitive type are stored directly within the memory block representing the object.